# Test for string equality / string comparison in Fish shell?

Tags: fish

How do you compare two strings in Fish (like `"abc" == "def"` in other languages)?

So far, I've used a combination of `contains` (turns out that `contains "" $a` only returns `0` if `$a` is the empty string, although that hasn't seemed to work for me in all cases) and `switch` (with a `case "what_i_want_to_match"` and a `case '*'`). Neither of these methods seem particularly... correct, though.

Comment: So, turns out `[` is actually a command (`/bin/[` on OS X), **as well as** a Bash builtin, with different syntaxes. Go figure!

Comment: this comment just made my day! The [ command is a really powerful tool.

Comment: Personally, I've actually started using `test` instead of `[` in all my scripts, so that it's clear that it's an external command and not a part of the language. (`test` and `[` are the exact same tool.) Of course, I think `test` is also a Bash builtin.

Comment: I should probably update this to point out that in Fish 2.x, `test` and `[` are both builtins. However, they have the same syntax as the external `[` command, so the accepted answer is still correct.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
  if [ "abc" != "def" ] 
        echo "not equal"
  end
  not equal

  if [ "abc" = "def" ]
        echo "equal"
  end

  if [ "abc" = "abc" ]
        echo "equal"
  end
  equal
```

or one liner:

```
if [ "abc" = "abc" ]; echo "equal"; end
equal
```

Comment: Aha! Odd, I thought I tried square brackets before; maybe it was the single `=` that threw me.

Comment: Yeah, the single '=' throws me as well.

Comment: shorter one liner: `[ abc = abc ]; and echo equal"

Comment: I like it. Coming from bash, I must say fish is doing it right!

Comment: Note that you must have a space between the square brackets and what's inside them. `[` is actually a shortcut to the `test` command, and `]` is an argument to `test` telling it to stop reading args. Without the spaces, `[` isn't interpreted as a command and/or `]` isn't present as an argument.

Comment: @BallpointBen, Thanks for your reminder. The `space between [` you mentioned drives me crazy. Fortunately you point it out. You saved my day Bro!

Answer (score 24):

The manual for `test` has some helpful info. It's available with `man test`.

```
Operators for text strings
   o STRING1 = STRING2 returns true if the strings STRING1 and STRING2 are identical.

   o STRING1 != STRING2 returns true if the strings STRING1 and STRING2 are not
     identical.

   o -n STRING returns true if the length of STRING is non-zero.

   o -z STRING returns true if the length of STRING is zero.
```

For example

```
set var foo

test "$var" = "foo" && echo equal

if test "$var" = "foo"
  echo equal
end
```

You can also use `[` and `]` instead of `test`.

Here's how to check for **empty strings** or **undefined variables**, which are falsy in fish.

```sh
set hello "world"
set empty_string ""
set undefined_var  # Expands to empty string

if [ "$hello" ]
  echo "not empty"  # <== true
else
  echo "empty"
end

if [ "$empty_string" ]
  echo "not empty"
else
  echo "empty"  # <== true
end

if [ "$undefined_var" ]
  echo "not empty"
else
  echo "empty"  # <== true
end
```